# ASP.NET Razor C# Html.ActionLink to create empty link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How would you use an `Html.ActionLink` to render the following link -

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

It may seem silly to do this, but sometimes I need a link that has link functionality (rollover pointers, etc.) but does not go anywhere. And I want to use an Html.ActionLink for code consistency.

I have tried different variations of `Html.ActionLink` but I keep getting messages about things not allowed to be null.

Comment: If that's all you need in the link, why not just use exactly that? Skip Html.ActionLink all together. Is there something specifc you need from Html.ActionLink?

Comment: agreed. just use an anchor

Comment: I have tried different variations of `Html.ActionLink` but I keep getting messages about things not allowed to be null. I want to use an `Html.ActionLink` for code consistancy, and I want a link to exist, with anything happening when it's clicked. Thanks!

Comment: ActionLink produces a link to an action as the name suggests. You don't want a link to an action, so ActionLink isn't the right tool. You could create your own helper method if you need this functionality often.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "", "", new {href="javascript:void(0)"})
```

will render as

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> </a>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. But my problem is I want a no "Link Text" and your solution gives me **Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText**

Comment: Will just a space work?  Otherwise we can try a custom helper method.  Out of curiosity how are the rollover pointers triggered if there is no content to roll-over?

Comment: A blank space worked! Thanks! Sorry for my dopiness. To answer your question, the link is in a `div` that has a background image.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of forcing ActionLink to do something it isn't made for, consider creating your own helper method:

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EmptyLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText)
    {
        var tag = new TagBuilder("a");
        tag.MergeAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
        tag.SetInnerText(linkText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
    }
}
```

Import the namespace into your view and you'll be able to do this:

```
@Html.EmptyLink("My link text")
```